# In dplyr 0.5.0, on a grouped data frame, why does slice(1) not give the same row ordering as filter(row_number() == 1)?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am observing that `slice` changes the ordering of the rows in some circumstances when `group_by` is used.

```
tmp_df2 <- data.frame(a = c(1, 3, 2, 4), b = c(1, 2, 3, 4))

tmp_df2 %>%
    group_by(a) %>%
    slice(1)
```

gives

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
Groups: a [4]

      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     2     3
3     3     2
4     4     4
```

and

```
tmp_df2 %>%
    group_by(a) %>%
    filter(row_number() == 1)
```

gives

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
Groups: a [4]

      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     3     2
3     2     3
4     4     4
```

It looks like `slice` reeorders the output in ascending order of the grouping variables. However, the documentation suggests that `slice` and filter should behave in the same way, particularly from `?slice` (*emphasis mine*):

> Slice does not work with relational databases because they have no intrinsic notion of row order. *If you want to perform the equivalent operation, use filter() and row_number().*

Comment: It _is_ returning the same data, just in a different order. (dplyr has always played a little fast and loose with row order, ostensibly because databases do.) If row order is useful information, make it a variable.

Comment: In my opinion, that is not good enough. Imagine if you did a `mutate` operation and it returns the rows in a different order!

Comment: It's part of tidy data. Every variable should be a column, including row order, if it has some meaning. If you think it's worth changing the code, write a pull request, but most of these decisions were thought out by Hadley, Romain, and co.

Comment: I must have missed the memo emphasizing your point then. In any case, assuming you are right, then I make the argument that the function is badly documented. Further, I am pretty sure these two functions behaved exactly the same (w.r.t my example) in the version previous to 0.5.0

Comment: I have now posted this issue in github: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/2192

Comment: Have you checked how `order_by` work? Have a look of `?order_by`. This is related to your first comment with `mutate`.

Comment: @jazzurro, is it always necessary to specify the order using `order_by` if you are doing a `cumsum` on grouped data?, or will it do the cumulative sum according to the current ordering in each group?

Comment: The point of the examples is that a certain variable is not in order, but you can still do cumsum in a right way by using order_by. So if you want to assign row number to a new variable based on an order of a variable, order_by would help you.

Comment: For those of you who cast a close vote, please suggest how I can make my question clearer than asking: "why does operation x give different results to y when the helpfile suggests they should be the same?"

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the code, `slice()` works by iterating over the groups, and so its output will be in group ordered form. I suspect it is more efficient than the equivalent `filter` approach, and that is why it actually exists - as otherwise there is no benefit to its inclusion.

*I would have left this as a comment, but I don't have enough rep - so be gentle with down-voting if I'm wrong*

Comment: That at least is a lead, does iterating over the groups explain the difference in output? Does this mean the documentation `?slice` is wrong? `# Equivalent code using filter that will also work with databases,
# but won't be as fast for in-memory data. `

Comment: By iterating over groups it has to choose some order for that iteration, I am assuming that this explains the differences. I think you're right though, the documentation makes it sound like they are equivalent, but I think they are not.

Comment: I just wonder if the filter approach creates the result of the slice approach when we use databases like SQL. The difference we see here may be something intentionally done so that users can get the result of the slice approach with a database. I am simply guessing.

Comment: Thanks, your answer has suggested a way of creating a minimal working example of this behaviour, which I have updated the question with.